# How to create a tag based on previously create tag's hash?

Tags: bash, git, github

I am trying to write a script that will create a tag and then create a draft release based on that tag. Essentially replicating the flow of what happens when you create a release via the Github website release flow below.

I am currently doing the following to create the tag and then the release:

```bash
# get latest commit hash of master
hash=$(cat .git/refs/heads/master);

# create tag based on commit
git tag -a $version $hash -m $version;

# push tag to github
git push origin $version --no-verify;

# commit has of newly created tag
tagHash=$(git rev-list -1 $version);

# # create release
gh release create $version --draft --generate-notes --title $version --target master;
```

It appears to always create a release and compares changes to the last minor version as opposed to most recent release.

For example, running the script above creates a release with

```
Full Changelog: v1.14.1...v1.15.3
```

But if I create the release via the web UI, it generates the following instead:

```
Full Changelog: v1.15.2...v1.15.3
```

I think I need to update my script to create a tag based on the previously create tag's hash as opposed to creating it from master/main?

i.e.:

```bash
# how can I get $lastTagsHash?
# create tag based on commit 
git tag -a $version $lastTagsHash -m $version;
```

Comment: Looks like I need to replace `hash=$(cat .git/refs/heads/master)` with hash of the latest release

Comment: Do not do `hash=$(cat .git/refs/heads/master)`, do `hash=$(git rev-parse refs/heads/master)` instead for instance. There's no guarantee that the unpacked ref even *exists*. Generally you *do* want to create a tag for a release from a hash ID found via a branch name like this though. There's no point in creating a *second* tag for an existing hash ID: a tag name is merely a human-readable version *of* the hash ID (perhaps with some extra metadata in the annotation, if it's an annotated tag).

Comment: To resolve an annotated hash name to a commit hash ID, use, e.g., `git rev-parse refs/tags/${tag}^{commit}`. The literal `^{commit}` suffix tells rev-parse to find the commit hash ID, rather than the annotated tag object hash ID. If the tag does not exist or resolves to a tree or blob hash ID, you'll get an error, so always check for errors. Note that the literal hat or caret character `^` *must* be passed through to rev-parse; if you're using CMD.EXE this requires doubling it (or perhaps some other quoting technique—I avoid Windows in general).